# How to get array from localstorage in Firebase Cloud Functions?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, firebase, google-cloud-functions

After sending the localStorage to server the `const arrayOrders` is showing up as empty even it contains values in client side.

I've tried to do that with this way but it not works.

Here is my code from server side and client side for requests handle.

What's wrong?

In server side :

```
exports.wip = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
  cors(req, res, () => {
    const url = `${req.protocol}://${req.get('host')}/work-in-process`;
    const tokenId = req.get('Authorization').split('Bearer ')[1];
    const arrayOrders = req.headers['service']; // {}
    const wipReq = JSON.stringify({
        operator: req.body.uid,
        conditions: req.body.status,
        service_list: {
            orders: [arrayOrders]
        }
    })
    return admin.auth().verifyIdToken(tokenId)
      .then((decoded) => {res.redirect(302, url.href)})
      .catch((err) => res.status(401).send(err));
  });
});
```

In client side :

```
$(function() {
    'a long time ago user recorded a' localStorage.setItem("service_array", array);
    $('.SubForm').on('submit', function(e) {
        $.ajax({
          type: 'post',
          url: 'http://localhost:3000/wip',
          data: $(this).serialize(),
          success: function(data) {
            if (data.status) {
              $.ajax({
                type: 'get',
                url: 'http://localhost:3000/wip',
                beforeSend: function(xhr) {
                  xhr.setRequestHeader('service', localStorage.getItem("service_array"));
                },
                success: location.href = "http://localhost:3000/wip"
              })
            }
          }
        });
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

> Storage objects are simple key-value stores, similar to objects, but they stay intact through page loads. **The keys and the values are always strings (note that, as with objects, integer keys will be automatically converted to strings).** You can access these values like an object, or with the `Storage.getItem()` and `Storage.setItem()` methods.

From: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API/Using_the_Web_Storage_API

So storing an array in `localStorage` may have mixed results. I would suggest:

```
$(function() {
  var data = [];
  var storeData = JSON.stringify(data);
  localStorage.setItem("service_array", storeData);

  $('.SubForm').on('submit', function(e) {
    $.ajax({
      type: 'post',
      url: 'http://localhost:3000/wip',
      data: $(this).serialize(),
      success: function(data) {
        if (data.status) {
          $.ajax({
            type: 'get',
            url: 'http://localhost:3000/wip',
            beforeSend: function(xhr) {
              xhr.setRequestHeader('service', localStorage.getItem("service_array"));
            },
            success: function(){
              location.href = "http://localhost:3000/wip";
            }
          });
        }
      }
    });
    e.preventDefault();
  });
});
```

It was not clear from your example where `array` was defined. Basically, you can use `JSON.stringify()` or `$.param()` to convert the Array data into String that can be stored to localStorage. Depending on your needs, you can convert it when you get the String back into an Array.

Hope that helps.